# Accessing Parent Functions with Java TreeMap/Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, treemap

I am probably just overlooking something, but I am working on the Team class and need to calculate the pitching and hitting stats of the players. The TreeMap roster is built using players so it can hold both Pitchers and PositionPlayers. I need to be able to call some of the functions from Pitcher and Position player but the TreeMap only lets me access the Player functions. How can I access the other functions? I have tried moving the players into other TreeMaps of the correct type but it says the class cannot be converted. Also, just looping through trying to call the needed functions. The program knows they are either Pitchers or PositionPlayers though, because of the overridden call toString() methods. Just curious how to access these other methods with minimal processing.

`Cannot find symbol` is the error.

The starts are where the problem comes up. I realize that the Player class does not have these functions and that is the scope, but I am not sure how to work around that.

```java
    public String calcHittingStats(){
        int count = 0;
        int totAtBats = 0;
        int totRunsBattedIn = 0;
        int totHomeRuns = 0;
        int totHitByPitch = 0;
        double totBattingAvg = 0.0;
        double totOnBasePercent = 0.0;
        
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, **Player**> player : hitters.entrySet()){
            totAtBats += player.getValue()**.getAtBats()**;
            totRunsBattedIn += player.getValue()**.getRunsBattedIn()**;
            totHomeRuns += player.getValue()**.getHomeRuns()**;
            totHitByPitch += player.getValue()**.getHitByPitch**();
            totBattingAvg += player.getValue()**.getBattingAverage**();
            totOnBasePercent += player.getValue()**.getOnBasePercent**();
            count++;
        }
        totBattingAvg = totBattingAvg / count;
        totOnBasePercent = totOnBasePercent / count;
        return " ";
    }
```

[image: UML for the code]

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with `instanceof` to check for types.

After this cast to to the dedicated type and assign to another local variable. With the new, correct typed variable you can call dedicated methods and fields.

Here a simple, but working example (you can run it):

```java
package temp;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TeamPlayGround {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TeamPlayGround().test();
    }

    private void test() {
        Team team = new Team();
        
        team.roster.put(1, new Pitcher("My-Pitcher"));
        team.roster.put(2, new PositionPlayer("My-PosPlayer1"));
        
        /* now iterate over the players: */
        for (Player player :team.roster.values()) {
            /* use instanceof to check for type at runtime */
            if (player instanceof Pitcher) {
                /* its an pitcher so cast it...*/
                Pitcher pitcher = (Pitcher) player;
                pitcher.doPitcherOperation();
            }
            /* same for position player */
            if (player instanceof PositionPlayer) {
                PositionPlayer positionPlayer = (PositionPlayer) player;
                positionPlayer.doPositionPlayerOperation();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private class Team{
        Map<Integer,Player> roster = new TreeMap<>();
    }
    
    private class Player{
        String name;
    }
    
    private class Pitcher extends Player{
        
        public Pitcher(String name) {
            this.name=name;
        }
        
        public void doPitcherOperation() {
            System.out.println(name + " is doing pitch operation");
        }
        
    }

    private class PositionPlayer extends Player{
        
        public PositionPlayer(String name) {
            this.name=name;
        }
        
        public void doPositionPlayerOperation() {
            System.out.println(name + " is doing position player operation");
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes more sense. Is there a way around instanceOf? there was something in the notes of the project where we should stay away from that. I am going to do more research on that subject tomorrow cuz I have been coding all day. If you have any way to point me in the right direction(not using instanceOf) That would be awesome too but this is a great clue for me to start finding a work around. Thank you for your help and time I will be working on this all day tomorrow as well :D

Answer (score 0):

This was the main solution to this problem:

```
if(player.getValue().getClass() == Pitcher.class){
Pitcher pitcher = (Pitcher) player.getValue();
```

I am not sure if this is considered good but it works. This is the entire function:

```
    public String calcPitchingStats(){
        int count = 0;
        int totInnings = 0;
        int totEarnedRuns = 0;
        double totEarnedRunAvg = 0.0;
        double totWhip = 0.0;

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Player> player : roster.entrySet()){
            if(player.getValue().getClass() == Pitcher.class){
                
                Pitcher pitcher = (Pitcher) player.getValue();
                totInnings += pitcher.getInningsPitched();
                totEarnedRuns += pitcher.getEarnedRuns();
                totEarnedRunAvg += pitcher.getEarnedRunAverage();
                totWhip += pitcher.getWhip();
                count++;
            }
        }

        totEarnedRunAvg = totEarnedRunAvg / count;
        totWhip = totWhip / count;
        return "Total Innings: " + totInnings + " Total Earned Runs: " +
                totEarnedRuns + " Total Earned Run Average: " + totEarnedRunAvg
                + " Total Whip: " + totWhip;
    }
```